# Delete Specific Audit Entries using SPAudit.DeleteEntries

Tags: spaudit, deleteentries

Currently, we can only delete all audit events that occurred before a specified date and time from the SharePoint Content DB, using the SPAudit.DeleteEntries method by passing the DateTime parameter. As far as I understand, there is no way to delete specific types of events. Can anyone one confirm by providing some valid references from authoritative sources like MSDN or Technet?

Also, what is the difference between Deleting entries and Trimming the Audit log? Can anyone explain clearly? Does trimming also clear / delete entries? The MSDN documentation is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

[SPAudit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spaudit_methods.aspx) doesn't contain method to delete specific SPAuditEntries, nor does [SPAuditEntry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spauditentry_methods.aspx) contain method to delete individual entry.

Also using common sense being able to remove specific Audit entries would not make much sense as one could easily wipe out traces of specific actions.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Do you have any reference to confirm? Also, more importantly, can you please let me know the difference between Trimming and Deleting Audit Logs?